# How to combine time series data with different granularity

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I have two dataframes:

```
df1
   value1   value2      timestamp     
0   193     68       2022-08-05 01:37:00
1   214     122      2022-08-06 01:55:00    
2   260     75       2022-08-07 02:16:00
```

value1 and value2 are recorded once everyday.

```
df2
     value3      timestamp  
0     0.01      2022-08-05 00:00:00 
1     0.0       2022-08-05 00:01:00 
2     0.2       2022-08-05 00:02:00 
3     1.0       2022-08-05 00:03:00 
...
4561  0.5       2022-08-07 12:30:00
```

value3 is recorded every 1-minute. I need to combine these into one dataframe by time.

value1 and value2 will be the same between each recordings. (ie. from 2022-08-06 01:55:00 until 2022-08-07 02:16:00, value1 should display 214 for every minute.

```
combined_df
       value1   value2    value3      timestamp     
0       193     68        0.02        2022-08-06 01:54:00
1       214     122       0.0         2022-08-06 01:55:00
2       214     122       0.1         2022-08-06 01:56:00
3       214     122       0.5         2022-08-06 01:57:00
...
4120    260     75        0.5         2022-08-07 02:16:00
```

Comment: How about a join? https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/merging.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to merge the two dataframes and then forward fill the missing values:

```
df1 = df1.merge(right=df2, on='timestamp', how='right')
df1.ffill(axis = 0, inplace=True)
```

Comment: thanks, this is useful but everytime i run this, it doubles the columns.

Comment: It shouldn't. Which columns does it double?

Comment: meaning that if i run it 4 times, there are value1_x, value1_y, value1_z, value2_x,  value3_y, etc.

Comment: FutureWarning: Passing 'suffixes' which cause duplicate columns {'value1_x, value2_x'} in the result is deprecated and will raise a MergeError in a future version.

Comment: also just noticed, this fills the missing values with the same numbers
value1 becomes 214 for all time points

Answer (score 3):

Use [`merge_asof`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html):

```
print (df2)
      value3            timestamp
0       0.01  2022-08-06 01:54:00
1       0.00  2022-08-06 01:55:00
2       0.20  2022-08-06 01:56:00
3       1.00  2022-08-06 01:57:00
4561    0.50  2022-08-07 12:30:00

df1['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['timestamp'])
df2['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['timestamp'])

cols = ['value1','value2','value3','timestamp']
df = pd.merge_asof(df2, df1, on='timestamp')[cols]

print (df)
   value1  value2  value3           timestamp
0     193      68    0.01 2022-08-06 01:54:00
1     214     122    0.00 2022-08-06 01:55:00
2     214     122    0.20 2022-08-06 01:56:00
3     214     122    1.00 2022-08-06 01:57:00
4     260      75    0.50 2022-08-07 12:30:00
```

Comment: jezrael - I never stop to learn from you!! was not familiar with the merge_asof. Kodus!